# Term used for a quantum or package of medication

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Whats the best term to describe how medication is counted?

For instance, "these pills come in 12 per pack 24 per pack or 100 per pack".

I'm trying name a column for a database, and I'm trying to have a short, but descriptive term for the quantum of medication that for instance a pharmacy would/could dispense on any given medication.

And I need someone coming after me to able to understand it.

Just to clarify, this column is not for stock level. The purpose of this database is to facilitate operation of a travel packing application. I was looking for a term used to accurately describe how many separate units contained per packaged unit (UNIT_PER_UNIT was the original term, which is vague). For instance, "12 pack of paracetamol", alternatively "1 tube of Antiseptic cream"- both are the smallest yet complete unit of either medication.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking for.  Medications come in other forms such as liquids and creams.  Will you be including such forms?  What are your other columns?  If you are only using pills, you can say _count_.  If using other forms of medication, you can say _quantity_ or _QTY_.  Some medications will come in liquids and pills, so you may need a column for _units_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest *Count,* in the following sense (OED):

> count, *n<sup>1</sup>* 2.a. The numerical result of reckoning; the
>   number reckoned up, the reckoning; the sum total.

*Count* is used in this fashion [here](http://drugpackage.com/product-catalogs/medication-blister-cards/), for instance:

> Drug Package offers both one and two piece Heat Seal Medication Cards . . . in . . . a range of blister counts including 7, 14, 28, 30, 31, 32, 60, 62 and 90 count.

If you have room, *Package Count* might be an option, but it might rather increase than decrease possible confusion. (It might be interpreted as number *of* packages.)

Regarding some of the other suggestions offered by various answerers, *Unit of Measure* would seem to be (for meds) something like “mg.” *Dose* might be either something like “25 mg.” (per capsule or tablet) or “2 capsules H.S.”

The [U.S. Food & Drug Administration](http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ucm254528.htm) uses the following field name but in their usage it is not a field for a simple number:

> **PackageDescription**   *Text/string*
>   A description of the size and type of packaging in sentence form. Multilevel packages will have the descriptions concatenated together.  For example: 4 BOTTLES in 1 CARTON/100 TABLETS in 1 BOTTLE.

Comment: regards PackageDescription unfortunately it will need to produce an integer value. Package Count is the safest so far, just worried if that could be confused with count/stock level of item ?

Comment: How about "count per package"?

Comment: I keep wondering if "count" could also be used for liquids... I imagine some of the drugs are in liquid form. Liquids are of course uncountable - but does that influence the applicability of "count" for liquids?

Comment: Good point, @AlicjaZ. But it seems to me that OP's example plus the stipulation (just above) that the values for this field will be integers together argue pretty strongly against the possibility of elixirs or tinctures; even were it stipulated somewhere that in their case units would always be ml., what would be done with a package containing 12 US fluid ounces (~354.9 ml.)? Still, how about heading this column of integers "Qty/Pkg"?

Comment: Each bottle would be individually opened and 4.9 ml would be removed via eyedropper ;) More seriously, I guess it does all depend on whether @Fionán is planning on keeping a database of only pills, tablets and capsules, or also syrups, ointments, drops etc.

Comment: Oooh, actually, _"the quantum of medication that a pharmacy would/could dispense on any given medication"_ actually implies that there's probably no problem with liquids etc, since those are always bought per bottle/container. Perhaps the question is about the name for the minimum amount of pills that a customer can buy (without buying the whole box)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be **"package size"**...

The FDA uses National Drug Codes for categorizing drugs, and one part of that code is the package size and type:

> For example, the NDC for a 100-count bottle of Prozac 20 mg is 0777-3105-02. The first segment of numbers identifies the labeler. In this case, the labeler code "00777" is for Dista Products Company, the labeler of Prozac. The second segment, the product code, identifies the specific strength, dosage form (i.e, capsule, tablet, liquid) and formulation of a drug for a specific manufacturer. In our case, "3105" identifies that this dosage form is a capsule. **The third segment is the package code, and it identifies package sizes and types. Our example shows that the package code "02" for this bottle of Prozac identifies that 100 capsules are in the bottle.** The FDA maintains a searchable database of all NDC codes on their website. [source](http://www.drugs.com/ndc.html)

Comment: had thought of of Package size but it could possibly describe its dimension, which is my only concern in any view where a user only sees the column names?

Comment: Hmm, I see your point, @Fionán. How about "Amount in package" or "units in package"? Do you have room for a separate field with "unit of measure"? Because otherwise, having an integer-only field will be hard (ml vs vs g vs units)...

Answer (score 0):

Unit of Measure is the standard industry term.

Comment: Wouldn't that be things like, "grams", "millilitres", etc.? That's the usage I'm familiar with - "amount" and "unit of measure" allow structures like "50" + "g", or "20" + "un"...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like **quantity** could be the word you seek.